# In embedded programming, when using uboot which dts files should i modify?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, u-boot

I need more references besides the uboot documentation. Is there anything that i can read to futher my understanding?

I am confused on what `dts` files my build is using when using **uboot**. Do I modify all the relevant `dts` files, for both `kernel/` and `uboot/` directories.

Or do i set it in a specific file? Can i tell which `dts` I used once I am booted into linux?

for example I am using an imx8mq-evk board, but there are many dts files to choose from.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's many parts to your question.  Lets start by looking at *configs/imx8mq_evk_defconfig* in U-Boot and in there we can see:

```
CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEVICE_TREE="imx8mq-evk"
```

So in this case, *arch/arm/dts/imx8mq-evk.dts* is the main dts and will #include all of the dtsi files it needs.  With one exception.  The file *arch/arm/dts/imx8mq-evk-u-boot.dtsi* will also automatically be included.

What files should you modify for U-Boot?  **ONLY** *arch/arm/dts/imx8mq-evk-u-boot.dtsi* is to be modified directly and all other files are a direct copy from the Linux kernel sources.  As an aside, yes, there are counter examples, but they are not following best practices.

What device tree will be passed to the kernel?  Well, that depends a bit on you.  Assuming you're using `bootefi` (and either an additional loader such as GRUB or systemd-boot, or just booting the *Image* file from the kernel build directly), if you don't pass in the address in memory of a device tree, the one U-Boot is using will be passed.  Otherwise you would `load` a dtb file from some other source, typically to the address in memory that `$fdt_addr_r` points to, and then pass that as the second parameter to `bootefi`.  If you are booting with `booti` instead, the device tree you have loaded in memory is the third argument passed, and again typically `$fdt_addr_r`.

Now, you noted there's many dtb files, which is true, but there's no automatic logic for this platform to determine which peripherals are to be used, which is where all of the other variants come from, the additional IO you have configured on the EVK for your specific needs.

Comment: Wow thank you, that makes so much sense and I know what to research now if I continue to have trouble (loader).  Now if I may ask a follow up, the only included `dtsi` files are the ones explicitly stated as `included` in the beginning of the `dts` files correct? And if that `dtsi` also includes more, those as well. I just did not know if I was looking at the correct files.

Comment: Correct, dts files are passed through the C pre-processor, so #includes are followed from #includes and #defines work and so on.